# How to make Angularjs treat response as plain text instead of json?

Tags: angularjs

How to make Angularjs treat response as plain text instead of json?

I am requesting a json file which I want to interpret as plain text. In the success callback I am getting a json. How I get text back without transforming the json to text (using stringify)?

Comment: yeah you can use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer not to use JSON.stringify because sometimes the response may not be json.

Comment: otherwise you can change response type to `application/text`

Comment: tried this didn't work method: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    responseType: 'application/text'

Comment: responseType: 'text' also didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new function to use in place of the default `transformResponse`.

```
var rawResponse = function(value) {
  return value;
};

$http({
  url: '...',
  method: 'GET',
  transformResponse: rawResponse
});
```

This will literally return the response *exactly as it is provided*.